# Doxygen NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, plugins, doxygen, doxywizard

I have installed this plugin to the NetBeans

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/14326/doxygen-integration

And when I press Create Doxygen it appears this message error

> The preferences of Doxygen plugin are not set

Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. In NetBeans,

- navigate to **Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous**. Select the "Doxygen Integration" tab.
- enter the complete path to the doxygen executable in the "Doxygen Binary" (e.g. `/usr/bin/doxygen`, the entry depends on the OS and on your doxygen installation).
- enter the path to your NetBeans projects in the "Doxygen Configuration"
- click on "Create New Doxygen Configuration File" - Create.
- in the "Output Path", specify the directory of the project for which you wish to generate a documentation.

Return to your project, right-click and select "Create Doxygen". If all works as expected, the output directory specified above should now contain an html and a LaTeX version of the documentation.

Hope this helps.